# Add Notes and Images to serialized VCF contact

Tags: swift, cncontact, vcf-vcard

I am trying to save a contact as a vcf using `CNContactVCardSerialization` which has worked out relatively well. I did find that apple doesn't include Notes or Images as part of the VCF.  I did use a [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45259691/412154) to help the images serialized but now I'm struggling with adding notes as well.

Here is what I've tried:

```
extension CNContactVCardSerialization {
    internal class func vcardDataAppendingPhoto(vcard: Data, photoAsBase64String photo: String) -> Data? {
        let vcardAsString = String(data: vcard, encoding: .utf8)
        let vcardPhoto = "PHOTO;TYPE=JPEG;ENCODING=BASE64:".appending(photo)
        let vcardPhotoThenEnd = vcardPhoto.appending("\nEND:VCARD")
        if let vcardPhotoAppended = vcardAsString?.replacingOccurrences(of: "END:VCARD", with: vcardPhotoThenEnd) {
            return vcardPhotoAppended.data(using: .utf8)
        }
        return nil

    }
    internal class func vcardDataAppendingNote(vcard: Data, note:String) -> Data? {
        let vcardAsString = String(data: vcard, encoding: .utf8)
        let vcardNote = "NOTE:".appending(note)
        let vcardNoteThenEnd = vcardNote.appending("\nEND:VCARD")
        if let vcardNoteAppended = vcardAsString?.replacingOccurrences(of: "END:VCARD", with: vcardNoteThenEnd) {
            return vcardNoteAppended.data(using: .utf8)
        }
        return nil
    }

    class func data(jpegPhotoContacts: [CNContact]) throws -> Data {
        var overallData = Data()
        for contact in jpegPhotoContacts {
            let data = try CNContactVCardSerialization.data(with: [contact])
            if (contact.note != "") || contact.imageDataAvailable {
                if contact.imageDataAvailable {
                    if let base64imageString = contact.thumbnailImageData?.base64EncodedString(),
                        let updatedData = vcardDataAppendingPhoto(vcard: data, photoAsBase64String: base64imageString) {
                        overallData.append(updatedData)
                    }
                }

                if contact.note != ""{
                    if let updatedData = vcardDataAppendingNote(vcard: data, note: contact.note){
                        overallData.append(updatedData)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                overallData.append(data)
            }
        }
        return overallData
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to be working.  I can get either the notes or the images section to work, but not both.

I'm likely not adding to the VCF file properly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Its not pretty but here's what I've done and its working for now:

```
extension CNContactVCardSerialization {
internal class func vcardDataAppendingPhoto(vcard: Data, photoAsBase64String photo: String) -> Data? {
    let vcardAsString = String(data: vcard, encoding: .utf8)
    let vcardPhoto = "PHOTO;TYPE=JPEG;ENCODING=BASE64:".appending(photo)
    if let vcardPhotoAppended = vcardAsString?.appending(vcardPhoto) {
        return vcardPhotoAppended.data(using: .utf8)
    }
    return nil

}
internal class func vcardDataAppendingNote(vcard: Data, note:String) -> Data? {
    let vcardAsString = String(data: vcard, encoding: .utf8)
    let vcardNote = "NOTE:".appending(note)
    let vcardFinal = vcardNote.appending("\n")
    if let vcardNoteAppended = vcardAsString?.appending(vcardFinal) {
        return vcardNoteAppended.data(using: .utf8)
    }
    return nil
}

internal class func vcardDataAppendingEnd(vcard: Data) -> Data? {
    let vcardAsString = String(data: vcard, encoding: .utf8)
    let vcardEnd = "\nEND:VCARD"
    if let vcardEndAppended = vcardAsString?.appending(vcardEnd) {
        return vcardEndAppended.data(using: .utf8)
    }
    return nil
}

internal class func vcardDataCleanEnd(vcard: Data) -> Data? {
    let vcardAsString = String(data: vcard, encoding: .utf8)

    if let vcardCleaned = vcardAsString?.replacingOccurrences(of: "END:VCARD", with: "\n"){
        return vcardCleaned.data(using: .utf8)
    }
    return nil
}

class func data(jpegPhotoContacts: [CNContact]) throws -> Data {
    var overallData = Data()
    for contact in jpegPhotoContacts {
        let data = try CNContactVCardSerialization.data(with: [contact])
        if (contact.note != "") || contact.imageDataAvailable {
            if let updatedData = vcardDataCleanEnd(vcard: data){
                overallData = updatedData
            }
            if contact.note != ""{
                if let updatedData = vcardDataAppendingNote(vcard: overallData, note: contact.note){
                    overallData = updatedData
                }
            }
            if contact.imageDataAvailable {
                if let base64imageString = contact.thumbnailImageData?.base64EncodedString(),
                    let updatedData = vcardDataAppendingPhoto(vcard: overallData, photoAsBase64String: base64imageString) {
                    overallData = updatedData
                }
            }
            if let updatedData = vcardDataAppendingEnd(vcard: overallData){
                overallData = updatedData
            }
        } else {
            overallData.append(data)
        }
    }
    return overallData
}
}
```