# CNContactVCardSerialization.data(with:) always returns nil result

Tags: swift, vcf-vcard

I am trying to retrieve all contacts and save them in VCard form (swift 4, XCode 9.0). But CNContactVCardSerialization.data(with:) always returns nil. Here is my code:

```
    var contacts = [CNContact]()
    let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch:[CNContact.descriptorForAllComparatorKeys()])
    do {
        try contactsStore.enumerateContacts(with: request,  usingBlock:
        { (contact:CNContact, result:UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) in
            self.contacts.append(contact)
        })
    }
    catch {
    }

    // at this point all contacts are in the "contacts" array.

    var data = Data()
    do {
        try data = CNContactVCardSerialization.data(with: contacts)
    }
    catch {
        print("some error in contacts:" + String(describing: error));
    }
    print(">>>data:" + String(data.count))
```

Output:

```
  2017-11-02 XXX [5224:449081] 
  Exception writing contacts to vCard (data): A property was not 
  requested when contact was fetched.
  2017-11-02 XXX [5224:449362] XPC 
  connection interrupted
  some error in contacts:nilError
  >>>data:0
```

I red the question below but it does not help.
[How to use method dataWithContacts in CNContactVCardSerialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32857466/how-to-use-method-datawithcontacts-in-cncontactvcardserialization)

I added "Privacy - Contacts Usage Description" into info.plist

Comment: Hi @Alex have you get answer?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to provide some specific keys to fetch?

UPD: Yep, if you want to fetch requests and serialize them, you have to set keys to fetch:
keysToFetch:@[[CNContactVCardSerialization descriptorForRequiredKeys]]

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out. Total craziness, if this is required, why not throw an error that tells us the problem?! All you get back is nilError. Angry face.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch:[CNContact.descriptorForAllComparatorKeys()])
```

To

```
let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch:[CNContactVCardSerialization.descriptorForRequiredKeys()])
```